# Neural Network in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, bitmap

I want to implement a very simple neural net in VB.NET.
I have array of integer, that is actually unmapped from black and white bitmap - we can assume every integer is 1 or 0. There is 1 spot painted on the bitmap, nothing else. I want to create and train the neural network to tell me if it's more like:
1-circle
2-square
3-horizontal line
4-vertical line
5-horizontal ellipse
6-vertical ellipse
7-horizontal and vertical elipses merged
8-vertical and horizontal elipses merged
9-2horizontal elipses merged
And the shapes are really ugly, but a person can clearly make this decision, so I think a NN can be easily trained to do that. But I'm new to neural networks, and I have no idea how to approach the problem, for example different spots have various sizes so I don't know how to get fixed number of inbuts to feed in my NN - resizing is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use an existing Neural Net implementation, I'd recommend checking out the [Accord.Net](http://accord-framework.net/) libary and the corresponding [Accord.Neuro namespace](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/N_Accord_Neuro.htm).

Neural nets have been used successfully for [handwriting recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handwriting_recognition), which may be close to your problem. Check out the article [Classifying Digits with Deep Belief Nets](http://tsunami.io/blog-DBN_Digits.html) which includes a sample using Accord.Net.

Note: you would need hand labelled set of data to train the neural net with.